# Google App Engine - serve php and static content from same directory

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

How do I serve both php and static content (e.g. jpegs) from the same directory on Google App Engine?  I have this app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

# Serve php scripts
- url: /subdir/(.+\.php)$
  script: subdir/\1

# Serve static content
- url: /subdir/
  static_dir: subdir
```

I can access e.g. /subdir/test1.php and /subdir/test1.jpg just fine from a browser when I run a local server with the "dev_appserver.py" command.  However, when I deploy to live instance on google app engine, only /subdir/test1.jpg is accessible (test1.php gives 404 ... which is unexpected).  When I remove the last 2 lines from app.yaml, only /subdir/test1.php is available (test1.jpg gives 404, as expected).

Is there a conventional way to server both static & php content to server out of the same directory on google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

See the accepted answer to my (sort of) similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682404/404-on-live-google-app-engine-while-working-on-local-sdk-server/46691770#46691770).

In short, you use the `application_readable` handler option like so:

```
# Serve static content
- url: /subdir/
  static_dir: subdir
  application_readable: true
```