# Problem with app.yaml file setting for appspot

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I have example app.yaml but am getting this error when I try to view link when done deploying:

```
This xxxxxxx.appspot.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: 
http://xxxxx.appspot.com/index.php
```

**APP.YAML settings:**

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: 
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
  application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: index.php
```

**Files in the dir are:**

```
app.yaml
index.php
post.php
pic.PNG
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682404/404-on-live-google-app-engine-while-working-on-local-sdk-server).

> In GAE when declaring a certain path static, it is then interpreted as a non-code path. All files within that path are therefore not accessible by the scripts running on the PHP environment with require or include.

Try to put all your static files under the `www.`  sub-folder and the non-static files in another sub-folder. Just try to separate them.